# Cisco ASA 5520 and "source routing based"

Tags: cisco, routing, cisco-asa, source

I have a Cisco ASA 5520 (8.3.x) with 3 interface active.

One HDSL internet connection (outsite1), one ADSL internet connection (outside2) and one for internal LAN (inside).

The default gateway is the HDSL connection.

I'm interesting to routing the intenal proxy server to ADSL internet connection.

With linux and "ip route table" it's possible.

Is there a way for this "source routing based" config?

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the ASA series does not support Policy-Based Routing (PBR) via the `route-map` command that you'd typically do in a Cisco router.

EDIT:

The [ASA 5500 Series FAQ](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_qanda_item09186a00805b87d8.shtml#pbr) confirms it.